# Hover effect for iframe , image is not fitted completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Well I am working on `<iframe src>` tag in which i am trying to add hover effect. What really this code does is that when i put my mouse over the yellow box it changes to cyan and red colour with 50 % height each divided vertically. But then I think what about adding an image so I just putted one image url and I noticed that it is not coming fit on that particular area. I tried changing the size or making position absolute ... but nothing worked in this.

My image file is this : 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Amanita_muscaria_After_Rain.jpg

Which is not fitting on that particular area.So is there any solution by which on hover I can get full size of that image on that particular area.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I have tried using `background-size: 100% 100%;` but then also its showing image like this.

[image]

**THIS IS WHAT I WANT** I have just edited to show you what I want

[image]

---

My code is divided into three parts

1. framehover.html

   ```
   <html>
   <body>
   <p style="height: 50px;">Move the mouse pointer into the yellow box, then directly into    
   the green box, 
   then out of both boxes. No red or cyan should remain, only yellow and green.</p>
   <iframe src="my.html" frameborder="0" height="300" scrolling="no" width="200"></iframe>
   <iframe src="my2.html" frameborder="0" height="300" scrolling="no" width="200"></iframe>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. my2.html - both my.html and my2.html is same so I am putting this one only. just difference is that in my.html `background-color: red;` for `.outer`

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
   body { margin: 0px; }
   .outer {
           margin: -100px;
       width: 400px;
           height: 500px;
       background-color: green;
   }
   .outer:hover {
           background-color: red;
   }
   .inner {

       visibility: hidden;
       width: 100%;
       height: 50%;
       background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Amanita_muscaria_After_Rain.jpg'); 

   }
   </style>
   </head>

   <body>
   <div class="outer" 
        onmouseover="firstChild.style.visibility='visible'" 
        onmouseout="firstChild.style.visibility='hidden'"><div class="inner"></div></div>
   </body>
   ```

---

Comment: @janaspage http://jsfiddle.net/8GZ97/ there is some problem which i am not able to correct it ... but this fiddle for sure will show you the working and my problem which I am facing.

Comment: @janaspage In simple words ... i want image to be fit on that particular small area .. i dont want that zoom i just want full image to be displayed on that half area ... when hover effect gets on .. if you can suggest any edit then u can i will accept it

Answer (score 0):

the iframe is independent of your website, you can not change the style of iframe, for that you must change it in the original Web. If you are in the same domain with js you can try, but you can have crossdomain error.